# RealmSwiftの一対多の初期設定について質問です。

Tags: swift, realm

現在、野球のDBアプリを作っております。
バッターとピッチャーのデータをRealmSwiftに登録し、
続いて、バッターのバッティングの詳細を設定しようとしています。
以下がバッターとバッティングの初期設定です。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Batter: Object {
    dynamic var team = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = ""
    dynamic var category = 0
    dynamic var tall2 = 0
    dynamic var body = 0

    let battings = List<Batting>()
}

class Batting: Object {
    let battings = List<Batting>()

    //打撃入力用変数 (RealSwift)
    dynamic var batDate = ""
    dynamic var gamesCount = 0
    dynamic var batterBoxSide = 0
    dynamic var battingsCount = ""
    dynamic var pitchersTeam = ""
    dynamic var pitchersName = ""
    dynamic var firstRunner = 0
    dynamic var secondRunner = 0
    dynamic var thirdRunner = 0
    dynamic var ballsCount = 0
    dynamic var strikesCount = 0
    dynamic var outsCount = 0
    dynamic var tamakazusCount = 0
    dynamic var pitchingJudge = 0
    dynamic var locateXX = 0
    dynamic var locateYY = 0
    dynamic var kyuushusCase = 0
    dynamic var dousasCase = 0
    dynamic var kekkasCase = 0
    dynamic var dakyuushu = ""
    dynamic var hokyuuPlayer = ""
    dynamic var kekkasCase2 = ""
    dynamic var dakyuuHoukou = ""
    dynamic var locateX1 = 0
    dynamic var locateY1 = 0
    dynamic var gidaCase = ""
    dynamic var datenCase = 0
    dynamic var kekkasCase3 = ""

    var batters: [Batter] {
        return linkingObjects(Batter.self, forProperty: "battings")
    }
}
```

最後の部分、

```
return linkingObjects(Batter.self, forProperty: "battings")
```

で、

```
‘linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)’ is deprecated: Use a LinkingObjects property
```

と怒られてしまいました。

バッターが一でバッティングが多になるため、この設定はどうしても必要です。
ネットで調べ、Xcodeで試し、問題ないと判断して、製作中のSwiftに書き込んだのですが、
何故か製作中のコードにこのエラーが出ました。
（テストコードには出ませんでした）

まだ、このDBを使って何かをしているわけではないので、このまま進めて良いのか？も不明です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return linkingObjects(Batter.self, forProperty: "battings")`という書き方は古い書き方なので、新しい表記法を使ってください、という警告です。
警告なのでエラーではありませんが、最新のバージョンではすでにその書き方はできなくなっているのと、新しい書き方の方が、いろいろと便利になっているので、新しい書き方に変えたほうがいいです。

```
var batters: [Batter] {
    return linkingObjects(Batter.self, forProperty: "battings")
}
```

の部分は、以下のように書き換えられます。

```
let batters = LinkingObjects(fromType: User.self, property: "battings")
```

新しい書き方のメリットは、計算済みプロパティから普通のプロパティになったので、逆方向の関連に対して、検索条件を指定できるようになったとか、自動更新が有効になるとか、そういう点です。
詳しくは、 https://realm.io/jp/news/realm-objc-swift-0.100.0/ を読みましょう。

質問とは関係ないですが、おそらく

```
class Batting: Object {
    let battings = List<Batting>()
```

上記の`let battings = List<Batting>()`は不要ではないかと思います。普通こういうモデリングはしませんので。

また、`LinkingObjects`についてもおそらく勘違いされていると思います。たぶん、その定義は必要なくて、`Batter`クラスの`let battings = List<Batting>()`だけで十分ではないかと思います。

Comment: ご教授有難うございました。お陰さまで解決しました。